# How to define specific page on hook_page_top?

Tags: 8, hooks

I want to add some stuff to the top of the page on certain pages.

How can I specify which pages that my custom content should be included on?

Comment: can you please elaborate your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the request object to figure out what page you are on and what to do with it.

Fx

```
$uri = \Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();
```

Maybe you want to get the route name instead:

```
$route = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
```

From there it's just a matter of defining your conditions in the hook.

Comment: this was the right. you got me

Answer (score 0):

To get the current raw path (the un-aliased Drupal path):

```
$current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
```